# Magento - blank/empty page when printing invoice on backend

Tags: php, magento, printing, view

I am working on Magento 1.5, and when I try to print any of my invoices, on the backend, I got a white/empty page.

I've tried to debug this step by step, the problem is that I can't put the error_reporting on (I'm on a production mode)

Update:

> [Mon Jun 10 12:35:53 2013] [error] [client 196.203.53.248] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of
>   Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible
>   with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct() in
>   /home/webmaster/public_html/www/lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource/File.php
>   on line 41, referer:
>   http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/sales_invoice/view/invoice_id/15/

Comment: have you checked your error log, both magento and php?

Comment: yes i've did it , nothing suspicious !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an incompatibility issue between PHP Version 5.4.4-14 and Zend Framwork.

Fixed it by commenting out `__construct()` and `__destruct()` methods in `lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php`

```
//    abstract public function __construct();

    /**
     * Object destructor. Closes the data source.
     *
     * May also perform cleanup tasks such as deleting temporary files.
     */
//    abstract public function __destruct();
```

Thank you !

Comment: Life saver, thank you!  Such a strange issue to have

Answer (score 13):

Edit

```
lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php
```

change

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

to

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```

Comment: to change the __construct method is exactly the correct solution. your welcome!

Comment: Because Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct(). To achieve this you need to have the same method signature, to be precisely you need to pass the param to construct as seen above.

Answer (score 6):

Mischa Leiss's and Rastaking's fixes are completely correct, thought I would like to add that editing the file at

```
[magento root]/lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php
```

is not best practice.  Better to copy the file to

```
[magento root]/app/code/local/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php
```

and edit the file there.  Magento will use this overriding version of the file, instead of the default, and you are less likely to run into issues in the future (like when you try to upgrade Magento core).

Also, this probably should have been a comment, but it was difficult to read without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

to

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```

Fixed the issue